# Substract average from all rows in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, average, aggregate-functions

I have a column with several values X, but I would want to compute the difference between each value and the average, i.e. X-AVG(X).

I tried:

```
    SELECT hours-AVG(hours) FROM users
```

However, this returns only one value, which is the first value minus the average.

How can I get a column with the difference between each value and the average of these values?

Answer (score 2):

You must subtract `(SELECT AVG(hours) FROM users)` from each column:

```
SELECT hours - (SELECT AVG(hours) FROM users) FROM users
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Sqlite 3.25 or newer, another approach uses a [window function](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html):

```
SELECT hours - avg(hours) OVER (ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
FROM users
```